# Problema para exportar tabela em formato xls com PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, xls

Boa tarde. Tenho um botão que gera um arquivo .xls que deveria trazer uma planilha a partir de uma pesquisa SQL... O arquivo é gerado, o problema é que aparece uma mensagem no Excel dizendo que o formato não corresponde. Onde estou errando?

Este é o botão:

```
<div style="float: right;"><a href="gerar_planilha.php"><button type="button">Gerar Excel</button></a> </div>
```

Aqui é o meu código do arquivo que gera o download:

```
<body>
    <?php 

    //Definição do nome do arquivo que será exportado
    $arquivo = 'planilhactts.xls';

    //Criamos uma tabela HTML com o formato da planilha
    $html = '<meta charset="UTF-8">';
    $html .= '<table border="1">';
    $html .= '<tr>';
    $html .= '<td colspan="2">Planilha de Contato</tr>';
    $html .= '</tr>';

    $html .= '<tr>';
    $html .= '<td><b>Nome Cliente</b></td>';
    $html .= '<td><b>E-mail</b></td>';
    $html .= '</tr>';

    //Selecionar os itens da tabela
    $result_ctts = "SELECT Empresa,EMail from payment_fornecedor";
    $resultado_ctts = mysqli_query($App_conexao, $result_ctts);

    while($row_ctts = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_ctts)){
        $html .= '<tr>';
        $html .= '<td>'.$row_ctts["Empresa"].'</td>';
        $html .= '<td>'.$row_ctts["EMail"].'</td>';
        $html .= '</tr>';
        ;
    }

    //Configurações header para forçar o download
    header ("Expires: Fri, 17 Apr 2020 16:50:00 GMT");
    header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT");
    header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header ("Pragma: no-cache");
    header ("Content-type: application/x-msexcel");
    header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$arquivo}\"" );
    header ("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data" );

    //Envia o conteúdo do arquivo
    echo $html;
    exit; ?>
</body>
```

Esse é o erro: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acho que o erro está aqui: `header ("Content-type: application/x-msexcel");` Tente usar: `header ("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");` Veja mais aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/103363/15361

Comment: Oi Andrei, obrigado pela atenção! Tentei fazer a alteração que você sugeriu, mas o erro permanece o mesmo... Mesmo assim obrigado.

Comment: Quando tive este problema resolvi utilizando o https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet

Comment: Isso realmente deve funcionar, o problema é que eu queria uma alternativa em que não precisasse importar uma biblioteca entende? Pois a versão do PHP que o ERP da minha empresa usa é o 5.6, e essa biblioteca que você mencionou é compatível com versões acima do PHP 7...

Answer (score 1):

troque seu header de Content-type para

```
header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
```

Comment: Tentei e permanece o mesmo erro... Mas mesmo assim obrigado pela ajuda.